# ¿Cómo puedo recoger la información de un ListView para compartirla con un boton?

Tags: android, listview

Muy buenas, quiero compartir la informacion que tengo en un Activity en la cual hay solamente un ActionBar con su boton de compartir y un ListView con una informacion precargada. Esa lista es la que quiero compartir pero no sé como hacer para pasar una lista entera, se como hacerlo por items seleccionados de la ListView pero la lista entera nidea. He buscado pero solo encuentro ejemplos con una imagen o texto plano. Se me ha ocurrido el recorrer la lista e ir metiendo uno a uno cada item como un String.

¿Hay forma de pasar toda la lista en conjunto?

El codigo para el menu es este:

`public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){`

```
    Cursor cursor;

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
        case R.id.mostrarTodos:
            cursor = gp.getModulos();
            ma = new ModulosAdapter(this,cursor);
            lvListaModulos.setAdapter(ma);
            break;

        case R.id.mostrarAprobados:
            cursor = gp.getModulosAprobados();
            ma = new ModulosAdapter(this,cursor);

            lvListaModulos.setAdapter(ma);
            break;

        case R.id.mostrarPendientes:
            cursor = gp.getModulosPendientes();
            ma = new ModulosAdapter(this,cursor);

            lvListaModulos.setAdapter(ma);
            break;
```

//Aqui el boton que quiero programar. He hecho esto por probar algo pero vamos que no tengo idea de como ponerle la lista entera.

```
        case R.id.compartir:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            ListAdapter lista = lvListaModulos.getAdapter();
            intent.setType("ListView");

            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, (Parcelable) lista);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Compartir"));


            break;
    }


    return true;
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cual es el código que has realizado? sería de buena ayuda agregarlo, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Si ahora lo edito. Es un menu en el que el id del boton es el de compartir